# QML dynamic object pass attributes

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

How can I pass through javascript attributes to a qml object that is not a text or a number. I want to pass the attribute to a value of a c++ property that sets the text of the attribute.

```
var component;
var gauge;

function createVerticalGauge(setWidth,setX,setY,setID,setText,setValue) {
    component = Qt.createComponent("verticalbargauge.qml");
    console.log(component.status)
    if (component.status == Component.Ready)
        finishCreation(setWidth,setX,setY,setID,setText,setValue);
    else
        component.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);
}

function finishCreation(setWidth,setX,setY,setID,setText,setValue) {
    if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
        gauge = component.createObject(adaptronicDash, {"id": setID, "gaugetext": setValue,
                                           "x": setX, "y": setY});
        gauge.width = setWidth;
        if (gauge == null) {
            // Error Handling
            console.log("Error creating object");
        }
    } else if (component.status == Component.Error) {
        // Error Handling
        console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
    }
}
```

The JS is called with this call:

```
Component.onCompleted: CreateVerticalGaugeScript.createVerticalGauge(300,10,300,"map","MAP",Dashboard.MAP);
```

**Dashboard.MAP** sets the Text property of the object.
Whem the object is created in the QML file directly,  the text gets set with Dashboard.MAP, but witht the script its just "0".

Dashboard.MAP is a qreal which comes from the class Dashboard that provides the values for my qml objects:

```
Q_PROPERTY(qreal MAP READ MAP WRITE setMAP NOTIFY MAPChanged)
```

How can i pass Dashboard.MAP with javascript. In my example *setValue* has the value *qml: undefined*

Comment: What is `MAP`??

Comment: A qreal variable in the registert c++ class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `Dashboard.MAP` only pass the `Dashboard` object reference to the function.

Then, when you create the attribute object, use this format:

```
"gaugetext": Qt.binding(function(){return setValue.MAP})
```

(remember, `setValue` is `Dashboard`)

This way `gaugetext` will be bound to `MAP` and will change with it.

Comment: I changed it in the JS to         gauge = component.createObject(adaptronicDash, {"id": setID, "gaugetext": Qt.binding(function(){return setValue.MAP}),   "x": setX, "y": setY}); but it is not working

Comment: adaptronicDash is the ID of the item wherein I call Component.onCompleted: CreateVerticalGaugeScript.createVerticalGauge(300,10,300,"map","MAP",Dashboard);    So i passed Dashboard, here are the 3 involved sources https://github.com/BastianGschrey/PowerTune/blob/Sensors/Gauges/verticalbargauge.qml   https://github.com/BastianGschrey/PowerTune/blob/Sensors/Gauges/DashAdaptronic.qml   https://github.com/BastianGschrey/PowerTune/blob/Sensors/Gauges/createverticalbargauge.js

Comment: sorry I compiled it again and its working. Thanks a lot. But one more question. With this solution I'm fixed to the value MAP of Dashboard. How can I change the js script to make also the source in Dashboars selectable? There are 50 more values like MAP

Comment: You can pass two parameters - `obj` and `propName`, so you pass `(Dashboard, "MAP")` - note you pass the property name as a **string**, and then inside the function instead of `obj.MAP` you can use the `obj[propName]` syntax so you can use any object and any property.

Comment: And how can I concat this value with a string. E.g. if I need a Unit behind that value?

Comment: @BastiAn - come on now, how long are you going to keep this going? It is simple - if you want something there, you have to 1 - pass it, and 2 - add it. If you want a unit, then pass a unit string, and `obj[propName] + unit`. But if you want the value to contain a unit string, then the property you bind to must also be a string. Because if it is a number it cannot possibly show anything other than a number.